upgrading from 22.04.3 to 24.04 using auto upgrade when complete the video fails to start
upgrading from 22.04.3 to 24.04 using auto upgrade when complete the video fails to start.
video was previously working with a nvidia-390 driver for my gf100gl [Quadro 4000] driver=nvidia lacency=0
Xorg.0.log

[   526.256]    compiled for 1.21.1.11, module version = 0.0.2
[   526.256]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   526.256] (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
[   526.256] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   526.256] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   526.256] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   526.256] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   526.257] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   526.257]    compiled for 1.21.1.11, module version = 0.0.2
[   526.257]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   526.257] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[   526.257] vesa: Refusing to run, Framebuffer or dri device present
[   526.257] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -2
[   526.257] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   526.257] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   526.257] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   526.257] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   526.257] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"

remotely logging into this machine to get info so its slow.
any help appreciated if more info needed just ask Thanks
Jim
213,1         94%
Second day trying to recover failed upgrade. Now through my efforts the screen displays "Oh no! Something has gone wrong" error.  So it seems to be worse off then before.
I've read and tried the possible fix
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo reboot
but the network is unable to connect to the internet but the local net is working so I can ssh into the machine. Trying to ping google.com results in the answer
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution.
System is on half of a nvme drive. Hate the thought of installing a clean 24.04 into the other half and then copying files for broken side.
Any Help Appreciated
Jim
